# Array PHP to javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I am not sure whether I am asking a dumb question again or not but because I am really a newbie in javascript and php so do hope that someone can help me out on this.

The problem I am facing now is I now have a PHP array named "$horse_info" which consists of all info of horses. Now I will like to display selected horse info once at a time.  I was told to use javascript so that it does not need to query from server each time. But how should I do that?

Here is my code and output:

```
<td> Horse </td>
    <td colspan=2>
        <select onChange='goto(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)'>
        <?php foreach ($horse_info as $h_list) { ?>
            <option<?php if($h_list->HID==$horse_id){?> selected ="selected"<?php } ?>><?php echo $h_list->HNAME;?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td> Date Last Meeting </td>
    <td colspan= 2>  </td> <!-- this is where I will need to show last meeting of each horse once at a time. -->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you output the php array as a javascript object using `json_encode`?  It will convert the array to a JS object.

Assuming that you are using inline PHP, you could do something like this in your script tag.

```
var jsObj = <?php echo json_encode($arrayName);?>;
```

Comment: Hi,
Can you show me an example? I am not too sure what do u mean.. =( Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: I added a snippet to point in the right direction. This would convert your array to a javascript object.

Comment: OK, thanks. So it should be sth like:
<style> 
 var jsArray = <?php echo jsonencode($horse_info)?>
</style>
Is it? Btw, since I will have to display it on my table. So can I have it in a function?

Comment: no, style is for your css rules.  <script type="text/javascript"></script> is for your script.

Comment: oh ya, sry, i mean <style>.LOL. 
So can I put it this way? 
<script type="text/javascript">
 function get_last_meeting()
{
  var jsObj = <?php echo jsonencode($arrayName);?>;
}

</script>

Is it possible?

Comment: yes, that should set the object variable inline on that page. You can then access the array from more code within that script block or in a JS file, but I wouldn't recommend the later as it could result in your code breaking if you try to access the object from a page where it is not outputted.

Comment: Oh OK, I have managed to do it. Thanks. But now how should I do to display the array content once at a time to <td colspan= 2>  </td> (row of my table)? Sorry to keep asking =(

Comment: There are a few ways to do something like that. But, if you are just outputting that data to a table, why go through Javascript at all? Wouldn't it be easier to echo the contents of the PHP array directly into the table?  To write the contents of the array, you could do something like <script> document.write(jsObj[0]); </script> (which will output the first variable in the array.  Or if your cells are identified, you could do it after the HTML is loaded.  jQuery could make that easier.  This is way more complicated than it needs to be though. Just output directly to the table with PHP.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that but by doing so will keep refreshing the webpage which I was asked not to do so. That is why, I will need to come up with a javascript function. 
Yeah, I have tried using document.write();. But I am not sure what should I write on my <td> </td>. So far, I tried <td onLoad="get_last_meeting()"> </td> where get_last_meeting() just consists of document.write($jsObj[0]); 

Once again, sry for the troubles. If possible, sample code will be much appreciated.

Comment: If your are trying to get data without refreshing the page, then you probably should be doing some sort of AJAX call. The function described above will only output the data from the last time the page was refreshed. Take a look at jQuery and how to use it's AJAX functionality.  It is really powerful. That type of code example should probably be asked as a separate question.

Comment: Oh ok, I roughly get the idea already. It seems working though not full-fledged yet. Anyway, thank you so much for your help up till now =)